# Is it advisable to use Game Center Player ID as a folder name inside the app bundle?

Tags: ios, game-center

I want to organize game persistent data in a way that all the data that belongs to a player goes in its respective folder. I was wondering if i can rely on player id to create unique folders in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to what others interpret, the documentation does not at all encourage the choice of player IDs as folder names. In fact, the format of a player ID is not guaranteed and may in the future contain characters that are not allowed to be included in a path name. Already today, the second character of a player ID is a colon (`:`), which seems like a bad character to include for a path name. The documentation explicitly states that no assumptions can be made on the format of a player ID.

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommends that you do use the player id for exactly this purpose.

> In addition to using player identifiers in your interactions with Game Center, your game should also use the player identifier whenever it wants to store data locally about a specific player. For example, if your game stores data to track a player’s progress (such as on the device, on your own server, or on iCloud), use player identifiers to distinguish between multiple players playing on the same device. That way, if a different player signs into the device, you can immediately personalize the experience by showing content specific to that player.

In any other situation where you want a string that is **Guaranteed** to be unique no matter what, you can use this:

```
NSString *guid = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
```

This can be used to uniquely name folders, files, assets, anything at all, and you can rest assured that it will never conflict with something your user or any other user ever creates [citation needed]

Comment: The documentation does not encourage the use of a player ID for a folder name, but other ways of local storage such as your own data structure inside a file or key/value storage in `NSUserDefaults` for example. Player IDs are not guaranteed to make valid folder names.

Comment: Good to know, I would have leaned towards the globallyUniqueString simply because I can test it more, and consequently feel more comfortable with what it does, while I have to just assume the playerID works similarly. Did I miss a specific line in the documentation about not using it for a folder name, or is that just experience talking?  FWIW, guid's make excellent (and unintelligible) folder names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it indirectly.
In the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html), "The identifier string is created when the player’s account is first created and never changes" "player identifiers are the only reliable way to track a particular player". 
Because the Player Id always be a string. You can just use hash or other algorithm to convert the playerid string to a safe format.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Apple documentation,](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html) it is really clear about each player being uniquely identified by a player identifier string.

Just don't make any assumptions about the format or the length of the string.

To be sure to make it not conflict with any other folder, by any strange coincidence, I would put your player folders in a subfolder of your own making.